# Private доступ на java

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно использовать private доступ методу.

```
private static final String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

public void printDayWeek(int numbDayWeek) {
    if (numbDayWeek >= 1 && numbDayWeek <= 7) {
        System.out.println(days[numbDayWeek - 1]);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Incorrect input data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой метод вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: printDayWeek он public

Comment: private days это не метод

Comment: "printDayWeek он public" тогда если я правильно понял         package numbdayweek;

public class NumbDayWeek {

    
    public void printDayWeek(int numbDayWeek) {
        private static final String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
      if (numbDayWeek >= 1 && numbDayWeek <= 7) {
            System.out.println(days[numbDayWeek - 1]);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Incorrect input data");
        }         
    }
    
}

Comment: В чём у вас проблема? Код не работает?

Comment: да код не работает

Comment: работает!!!!!!!

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA выдает ошибку:
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\JavaAndroid\DayWeek\out\production\DayWeek" DayWeek
Error: Main method not found in class DayWeek, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application